# Auto-move posts to a different category on post end date?

Tags: wordpress, date, categories

Is there a way to set an end date to a post and automatically move it to a different category when that end date hits?

Is there a way to set up a custom post order?  More specifically, I'm looking for a way to order by date.  Not post date, but a date that I set myself.

Answer (score 1):

A solution to your problem could be the Content Scheduler plugin. You can download it here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/content-scheduler/ and see if it works well for you. Some people reported that it wasn't working all the time, but you might get lucky and the developer seems like a nice and involved chap willing to help with whatever issues. The plugin does not currently support custom taxonomies.
About the date issue, however, I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

Update 1/1/1014, I've spent 2 weeks on trying to get the Content Scheduler working.  It will NOT work on Multisite enabled Wordpress installations.  I've attempted to contact the developer and received no response.  I'm currently searching for an alternative which is why I found this post.  Figured I'd provide an update so people don't waste their time.